# Radio buttons in one column with Perl's HTML::Template

Tags: perl, radio-button

This is a two-column table with a label in the left-hand column and form elements in the right-hand column. I am trying to get the radio buttons for the chair color all in the second column. But they keep ending up in the first column.

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
use HTML::Template;
use CGI qw(:standard);

my $form = '';

$form .= start_form .
  table ({-width=>'100%'},
    Tr([
      td (b ('Chair color:')),
        td (radio_group(-name => 'certificate_type',
                        -values=>['blue','white','green'],)),
      td ([b ('Username:'),  $ENV{REMOTE_USER}]),
      td ([b ('Full name:'), $PARAMS{CURRENT_FULLNAME}]),
      td ([b ('Email:'),     $PARAMS{EMAIL}]),
   ])) . submit('Submit') . reset . end_form;
```

(Even better would be to get the buttons in the second column but stacked vertically.)

Comment: That looks like a five column table.

Comment: @mob: that isn't how CGI does things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want "Chair colour" in the first column, to the left of the three radio buttons in the second column?

The problem is that you have put "Chair Colour" and `radio_group` in two separate `td` elements, so they will appear on separate rows.

You need to pass them together, enclosed in an anonymous array, to a single `td` call, as you have the last three rows.

Also, a parameter of `-columns => 1` to the `radio_group` will force them into a single column.

This code seems to do what you need.

```perl
my $form =
    start_form
  . table( {-width=>'100%'},
      Tr([
        td([
          b('Chair color:'),
          radio_group(
            -name => 'certificate_type',
            -values => [ qw/ blue  white  green / ],
            -columns => 1
          )
        ]),
        td([b('Username:'),  'remote user']),
        td([b('Full name:'), 'current fullname']),
        td([b('Email:'),     'email']),
      ])
    )
  . submit('Submit')
  . reset
  . end_form;
```

Comment: How would you do it if you wanted all three radio labels and buttons to be in the second column but instead of stacked vertically they were all on the same line and even with the label "Chair color"?

Comment: @rlandster: then just change `-columns => 1` in my code to `-rows => 1`